# Delete XML node from the varchar message type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete two XML nodes from string data type in SQL Server query. I have tried with multiple options as .modify and replace but it is not working.

Sample XML

```
<Info>
    <Name>Rajesh</Name>
    <Age>Rajesh</Age>
    <School>KSR</School>
</Info>
```

- Table name : `Person`
- Column name: `Data Varchar(60)`

I am trying to remove the `Age` and `School` elements from the above XML.

The output I need is

```
<Info> 
     <Name>Rajesh</Name>
</Info>
```

I have tried with below command, but it is not working, please help to solve this

```
SELECT CAST(DATA AS XML).modify('delete /Info/Age')* 
FROM Person;
```

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: Seems you need to cast first to XML. Have you try ```UPDATE Person SET Data = CAST(Data AS XML).modify('delete /Info/Age')```??

Comment: Did you happen to read the [modify() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type) documentation? _The modify() method of the xml data type can only be used in the SET clause of an UPDATE statement._

Answer (score 1):

You would need to first convert it `xml`, then use `.query` to rebuild the XML excluding those two node names, then cast it back.

```sql
UPDATE p
SET Data = CAST(v.xml.query('
  <Info>
  {
    /Info/*[local-name() != "Age" and local-name() != "School"]
  }
  </Info>
  ') AS varchar(max))
FROM Person p
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT CAST(Data AS xml)
) v(xml);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/bWe5djiv)

I shouldn't need to tell you that `varchar(60)` is an entirely inappropriate data type for this. You should be storing this as `xml` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise version. A minor improvement on the @Charlieface answer.

Just two chained TRY_CAST() calls which makes `FROM ...` and `CROSS APPLY` clauses unnecessary.

Additionally, the XPath predicate is using a *sequence* of XML elements to be removed.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Data NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (Data) VALUES
(N'<Info>
    <Name>Rajesh</Name>
    <Age>Rajesh</Age>
    <School>KSR</School>
</Info>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl
SET Data = TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(Data AS XML).query('<Info>{
    for $x in /Info/*[not(local-name()=("Age","School"))]
    return $x
    }</Info>') AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

-- After
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    SELECT '<Info><Name>' +
    (
        SELECT CAST(Data AS XML).query('
            <Info>
                {
                    for $node in /Info/*
                    where not($node/self::Age or $node/self::School)
                    return $node
                }
            </Info>
        ')
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    + '</Name></Info>'AS PersonName
FROM 
    Person;
```

Comment: That returns `Rajesh` which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: It will return the actual result which OP needs.

<Info>
    <Name>Rajesh</Name>
</Info>

Comment: I suggest you test it, because check this out https://dbfiddle.uk/RZmM8EK2

Comment: And when you correct your answer, all answers should contain an explanation in addition to a query.

Comment: Bro, you can concat the constant tag its not a big deal.

Comment: Please don't call me bro... and totally a big deal, you can assume that OP wants a process that works more generally than a specific case of having to re-add tags...

Comment: Listen up, champ. In the real world, precision matters. We're not here to play guessing games. We tackle the problem head-on and deliver results. So, suit up or step aside

Comment: Please don't call me champ... and I suggest taking you own advice and provide a solution that **actually** answers OPs question.

Comment: is my solution provides everything that OP needs?